# Understanding android dialog layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout, dialog

I'm making a simple custom dialog for my android app, displaying only a seek bar. However, the complications of this simple task are driving me nuts.

My layout for the dialog is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">

<SeekBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialogVolumeSlider"
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The dialog is created in code:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
return d;
```

Instead of a simple box wrapping the seekbar, I get this phantom space coming from somewhere:

[image: Problem screenshot]

What's the issue here? I've tried modifying

```
d.getWindow().getAttributes().height
```

but this creates additional problems as well.

Thanks for any help!!

EDIT: Stranger things happen when I assigned a fixed "50dp" to my LinearLayout's layout_height:
[image: Second problem]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default a `Dialog` will leave space for a title even if you don't set one (with `d.setTitle()`) .

You can either set a title to fill the space or request that the `Dialog` not have a title.
Here is an example of how to request the no title setting.

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
d.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
```

With no title, your `SeekBar` will appear as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a fixed Height on your parent linear layout. Something like:

```
android:layout_height="50px"
```

Comment: See edit, it just cuts off the linear layout, and still shoves it towards the bottom of the box.